# AWX y PHP via API

Tags: php

Quería saber si hay alguna manera de tener la siguiente estructura:

1. Un servidor de ansible awx con playbooks ya insertados.
2. Un entorno web que accede a este servidor de awx mediante una api.

¿Es posible que esta conexión se haga por php a través de una key pueda acceder a un servidor awx para ejecutar trabajos?

Comment: Creo que es esto lo que buscas? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.3.0/html/towerapi/auth_token.html Saludos.

Comment: Si pero era más bien lo siguiente: teniendo un wordpress con un botón, acceder al awx para que se ejecute un job por ejuemplo

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes realizar una llamada por POST a este endpoint /api/v1/authtoken/

Pasandole usuario y password:

content-type: application/json
body: {"username": "user", "password": "my pass"}

Esto te devuelve un token:

{
    "token": "8f17825cf08a7efea124f2638f3896f6637f8745",
    "expires": "2013-09-05T21:46:35.729Z"
}

Ahora usas el token para agregarlo en la cabecera de autorización:

Authorization: Token 8f17825cf08a7efea124f2638f3896f6637f8745

Hasta aquí solo es para poder obtener los credenciales necesarios para poder interactuar con AWX

Ahora para crear un JOB debes usar el endpoint /api/v1/jobs/ y enviarle lo siguiente por POST, recuerda la cabecera de Authorization:

```
name: (string, required)

description: (string, default=””)

job_type: (multiple choice, required)
run: Run (default)
check: Check
scan: Scan
inventory: (field, default=None)

project: (field, default=None)

playbook: (string, default=””)

credential: (field, default=None)

cloud_credential: (field, default=None)

forks: (integer, default=0)

limit: (string, default=””)

verbosity: (multiple choice)
0: 0 (Normal) (default)
1: 1 (Verbose)
2: 2 (More Verbose)
3: 3 (Debug)
4: 4 (Connection Debug)
5: 5 (WinRM Debug)
extra_vars: (string, default=””)

job_tags: (string, default=””)

force_handlers: (boolean, default=False)

skip_tags: (string, default=””)

start_at_task: (string, default=””)

job_template: (field, default=None)
```

Click [Autenticación](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.3.0/html/towerapi/auth_token.html)
Click [Jobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.3.0/html/towerapi/job_list.html#create-jobs)

Saludos.

Comment: Buenas Francisco. Sobre tu reporte, te comento: Alvaro no marcó la publicacion como de baja calidad. Eso se hace automaticamente por el bot Comunidad. Y fui yo quien convirtió la "respuesta" a comentario. Ahora, tras tu edicion, ya es una respuesta válida. Gracias por editarla y por mandar el reporte. Un saludo